# Что использовать для реализации клиент-серверного приложения?

Tags: android, php, java, post, sql

Нужно реализовать клиент-серверное приложение. Принцип работы:

Клиент отправляет текстовую информацию на сервер. Сервер обрабатывает и раскидывает всем клиентам, которые подключены к сереру и выводит уведомление о поступлении новой информации. Используя tcp смог реализовать данную фичу (что то типо чата вышло).

1. Подскажите, что лучше использовать в качестве сервера и где лучше хранить все данные, + хотелось бы иметь типо кеша ( ну чтоб если что в оффлайне глянуть ).
2. В качестве сервера использую java приложение. Будет ли лучшим перенести на php и использовать post запросы? но без сокетов не смогу отправить всем уведомления в нужный момент.

Подскажите, в какую сторону копать?

Answer (score 2):

Как насчет реализации на nodejs и websocket? JavaScript знают многие, поэтому изучить nodejs будет не проблема. Есть готовые решения. В качестве хранения можно использовать noSQL БД, что позволит шустро работать. http://socket.io/demos/chat/ - как демо пример

Кстати, я думаю, что websocket можно реализовать на чем угодно, так что тут не принципиально переходить на nodejs. Можно доработать на Java.

Comment: спасибо, буду пробывать

Answer (score 0):

Сервера всегда лучше на JAVA если есть возможность. для данных создано БД)
НО пхп тоже не плохая штучка я слышал) поэтому все зависит от реализации, ибо с другой стороны JAVA машина имеет ряд недостатоков и хейтеров.

Comment: всегда.... никогда почти,  php для асинхронного сервера не годится почти, это надо php прям очень любить, чтобы асинхронно его программировать.

Comment: думаю остановиться на java или nodejs

Comment: разработчики ВК и их KPHP с тобой поспорили-бы) и фейсбук с их детищем где за основу взят так-же куски php

Comment: @Manitikyl с разработчиками ХХХ мы будем спорить, если столкнемся с ними сами. Вы-то какие аргументы можете привести?

---

В PHP, при всей моей любви к отрицанию заявлений "PHP не может в ХХХ", очень много недостатков в языке самом по себе и, действительно, абсолютно нулевая поддержка асинхронности, многопоточности и всего того байтового ликования, которое приходит с нагрузками.

Comment: у меня есть опыт попытки разработки(впрочем успешной) под phpdaemon и ReactPHP выводы - в следующий раз я на с++ лучше напишу, чем так корячиться.

----

а насчет всяких фэйсбуков/вк - они могут баблом паравоз топить, это круто, никто не спорит, и даже поедет, но у меня стока бабла нет чтобы разработку подобной сложности вести.